# Need Perl regex which matches every a software version starting from 3.10.1.0 and all further versions numbering

Tags: regex, perl, version

This is my test case.

A cmd_1, which was working until version 3.10.0.0, will not work in future versions. Cmd_2 is introduced in 3.10.1.0 and will be the valid replacement going forward.

I need to add a condition for the above scenario. For older versions before 3.10.1.0, cmd_1 has to execute, and for 3.10.1.0 and beyond, cmd_2 has to execute.

I tried as below:

```perl
if ( ( $version =~ /^3\.10\.[1-9]/ ) || ( $version =~ /^3\.[1-9][0-9]/ ) || ( $version =~ /^[4-9]/ ) {
    # execute cmd_2;
}else{
    # execute cmd_1;
}
```

The above regex fails in a few cases. For example, in the case of version= 3.10.0.0, cmd_2 will be executed, which is invalid.

Cmd_2 has to execute in versions like:

`3.10.1.0`, `3.10.2.0`, `3.11.0.0`, `3.11.2.0`, `3.20.0.0`, `4.0.0.0`, `5.0.0.0`, `10.0.0.0`

Cmd_1 has to execute in versions like:

`3.10.0.0`, `3.9.0.0`, `3.1.0.0`, `3.0.0.0`, `2.0.0.0`, `1.0.0.0`

I tried a few more regexes but was not able to find a perfect one. Please help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe `/^(?:3\.(?:10\.[1-9]\d*|(?:1[1-9]|[2-9]\d))|[4-9]|[1-9]\d+)\./`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/SbK2EM/2).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't use a regex pattern for this.

```
use version qw( );

if ($version >= version->declare("3.10.1.0")) {
   ...
} else {
   ...
}
```

Comment: This is definitely the right way to do this. I wasn't aware of the version package. Always a good day when you learn something new.

Answer (score 5):

This regex should do what you want.

```
^(?:[4-9]|[1-9]\d+)(?:\.\d+){3}|3\.[2-9]\d(?:\.\d+){2}|3\.1[1-9](?:\.\d+){2}|3\.10\.[1-9]\d?\.\d+$
```

It looks for all the cases where `cmd_2` should run i.e.

```
[1-9]x.x.x.x
[4-9].x.x.x
3.[2-9]x.x.x
3.1[1-9].x.x
3.10.[1-9]x.x
3.10.[1-9].x
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/3NTWnd/3)

Comment: This is awful. It's unreadable. It's unmaintainable. It forces all future versions to have 4 components (when versions often change formats over time in practice) because it considers 4.3 to be less than 3.10.0.1.

Comment: Yes, as @ikegami says, 4.3 is consider to be less than 3.10.1.0. 
But if software always returns its version as full string ie, 4.3.0.0 then above regex works fine.

Comment: You make it sound like 4.3 is short for 4.3.0.0, but there's no reason to believe that. So like I said, the answer actually assumes all versions will have exactly four numbers, but there's no way to predict that, and this kind of thing changes all the time, so this is a very fragile solution (which is particularly bad given how unreadable and unmaintainable it is)